# How do I resign app with entitlements?

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I have an .ipa file which I need to resign. I tried doing it as explained on the [objc.io blog](https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/inside-code-signing/):

```
$ codesign -f -s 'iPhone Developer: Thomas Kollbach (7TPNXN7G6K)' Example.app
```

However this is insufficient. When I do codesign I get something like this:

```
$ codesign -d --entitlements - Example.app/Example
Executable=/Users/myuser/Payload/Example.app/Example
```

I don't get any entitlements listed.

However if I do `codesign -d --entitlements` on the original IPA file from xCode I get:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>UFAYDHAUP.com.company.example</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
    <key>beta-reports-active</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>UFAYDHAUP</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>UFAYDHAUP.com.company.example</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I tried the line below

```
 codesign --entitlements Example.app/archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent -f -s 'iPhone Developer: Thomas Kollbach (7TPNXN7G6K)' Example.app
```

But the following keys are not included:

- beta-reports-activ
- get-task-allow

So how am I supposed to do this? I don't have an entitlements file, in xCode 7, one only checks Capabilities. And all I have is Apple Push notifications.

Finally to clarify my requirements:

1. I will not change App ID or use different provisioning profile or code signing identity compared to what xCode exports.
2. Only the main executable is changed with a tool, which is why a resign is needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is actually quite self evident in the question itself. The output from:

```
$ codesign -d --entitlements - Example.app/Example
```

Is actually a perfectly valid entitlements file. So you can store the output from the original .ipa exported from xCode by writing:

```
$ codesign -d --entitlements entitlements.xml Example.app/Example
```

This will store the entitlements in `entitlements.xml` which you can then use in an argument to sign the .ipa file yourself:

```
codesign --entitlements entitlements.xml   -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Company (UFAYDHAUP)" Payload/Example.app
```

Naturally "iPhone Distribution: Company (UFAYDHAUP)" has to be replaced with the signing identify you use and `Payload/Example.app` will be the path to your app which has been unzipped from the .ipa file.

Answer (score 11):

It helped me:

```
--preserve-metadata=entitlements
```

Saving and restoring entitlements are not needed anymore.

Comment: This did the trick for me. `codesign --preserve-metadata=entitlements --force --verbose --sign "Apple Development" MyApp.app`