# Editing contents of ipa file

Tags: ios, code-signing, ipa

I have an ipa file of my application.
What I am looking to do is to replace a folder inside the .app

So What I did till now :

1.Renamed the .ipa to .zip

2.Extracted the .zip file which gave me Payload/Appname.app folder structure.

3.Inside AppName.app -> Show Package Name -> MyTargetFolder

4.Replaced MyTargetFolder with required updates

5.Using terminal - used a command `codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: keychain certificate name"  Payload/*.app`
Above command gave output on terminal as : 
`replacing existing signature`

6. Re-zipped the Payload folder and then changed its extension to .ipa
7. Using Xcode, Tried installing the app on Device

However it is showing an error as : `App installation failed  There was an internal API error.`

Is there something missing in what I am doing?

Comment: Is your signing certificate listed in the embedded mobile provisioning profile? If not, you need to replace the profile with one listing your certificate and probably modify the entitlements.

Comment: ok... I did replace the existing embedded mobile provisioning profile with the one containing my certificate and fired the codesign command. Now when I try to install the app, it shows a message : `App installation failed > The application could not be verified.`

Comment: I might have missed this, but have you updated the entitlements for the new profile? I usually need to change the debug-entitlement and change the team identifier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888535/