# Is entitlement.plist file required while re-signing a development IPA with distribution certificate and profile of same account?

Tags: ios, code-signing, codesign, code-signing-certificate, code-signing-entitlements

In my organization, the distribution certificate and app store provisioning profile are located and installed on a Mac machine present inside a Lab environment to which only a lab manager has access to.

For me to upload an app's IPA to app store, I need to archive a development IPA (using dev cert and profile in Release configuration mode) on my local Mac and then send across this IPA to the lab manager.

The lab manager uses a python re-signing script to re-sign the IPA on the lab Mac.

Do I also need to explicitly send a entitlements.plist file along with the IPA. My app does not use any capabilities as of now, not even Push Notifications. All Capabilities in Xcode are Off and on developer portal also the app identifier has Game Center and In-House Purchase as checked by default under the Capabilities.

I am assuming since it is the same Apple account using which lab manager will be re-signing the IPA and the app store profile present on the lab Mac contains its own entitlements, I do not need to send an explicit entitlements.plist file. Also, I assume the app will not get rejected in review.

Are these assumptions correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can *not* magically attach an entitlements file during export; it has to be there during archiving. But you do not find out whether you got it "right" (in Apple's eyes) until distribution time.

So a situation where archiving happens in one place and exporting happens in another is not going to be a happy one.

I would describe this entire situation as unacceptable. I have had many occasions, just working on my own machine, where I was able to archive but then unable to upload to the app store or TestFlight because of an entitlements issue. And often there was no "real" issue: I just needed to do a bunch of goat sacrifices and fooling around with the settings (e.g. turn entitlements on and off). The point is, you don't know there's an issue until you export — and then to find out whether you fixed it you have to build / archive again.

Answer (score 1):

1) Entitlement plist can be given while resining an ipa like below but this is optional.

```
codesign --entitlements entitlements.xml   -f -s "IDENTITY" Payload/<app_name>.app
```

Please refer [How do I resign app with entitlements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888535/how-do-i-resign-app-with-entitlements)

2) To resign an ipa, you can follow below procedure (without giving Entitlement).

Requisites:

- Distribution profile
- Distribution certificate
- Assuming Distribution profile stored in Desktop ~/Desktop/AdHoc.mobileprovision

Procedure :

1) unzip ipa using following command,

```
unzip app.ipa
```

2) When you unzip it You will have as an output a directory called “Payload”.

3) remove _CodeSignature file from unzipped folder “Payload” as below

```
 rm -rf Payload/MyApp.app/_CodeSignature/
```

4) Rename distribution profile which is stored in Desktop  to embedded.mobileprovision

5) Copy distribution profile(embedded.mobileprovision from Desktop) to Payload/.app

```
cp ~/Desktop/AdHoc.mobileprovision Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

6) Resign using below commands,

```
codesign -f -s “IDENTITY”  --resource-rules Payload/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist  Payload/MyApp.app
```

7) Zip payload to form an ipa as below

```
zip -qr <app_name>.ipa Payload/
```